# Downloading .png image results in corrupted file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, urlfetch

I try to download an image with FetchUrl but it results in an 4kb corrupted file. I try to download this file:
[Parameter Link with redirects](https://api.apitemplate.io/03177b237ed25f0c@QPwLvlue/image.png?Datum1.text=maandag%205%2F12%2F22&Menu1.text=Seldersoep%0AQuornbolognaise%20%0AGeraspte%20kaas%0AVolkoren%20spaghetti&Datum2.text=dinsdag%206%2F12%2F22&Menu2.text=Tomatengroentesoep%0ABloemkool%20-%20kaasburger%20%0ABloemkool%0AGestoomde%20aardappelen&Datum3.text=woensdag%207%2F12%2F22&Menu3.text=Kervel-preisoep%0AVegetarische%20gyros%0AGroentenmix%0AFrieten&Datum4.text=vrijdag%209%2F12%2F22&Menu4.text=Jardini%C3%A8resoep%0AShoarmaburger%0AMosterdsaus%0APrinsessenbonen%0AGestoomde%20aardappelen)

I was thinking it had something to do with the fact that it's a redirection link, but UrlFetch follows redirects by default. I tried the direct (server cached) link and the same corrupted file is generated, this is the direct link: https://pub-cdn.apitemplate.io/2022/12/212ebbf4-8051-446b-bc3a-1a225b2a3758.png

This is the code:

```
function download() {
  let imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://pub-cdn.apitemplate.io/2022/12/212ebbf4-8051-446b-bc3a-1a225b2a3758.png").getBlob();
  DriveApp.getFolderById("1vb7ZzdhBfsK6t154Z2CR-RpBNEKvyPB6").createFile("menu.png", imageBlob, MimeType.PNG)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imageBlob` is a `blob` but not a `content`.

[`createFile(blob)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob) should be used instead of [`createFile(name, content, mimeType)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename,-content,-mimetype).

```js
function download() {
  let imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://pub-cdn.apitemplate.io/2022/12/212ebbf4-8051-446b-bc3a-1a225b2a3758.png").getBlob();
  const file = DriveApp.getFolderById("1vb7ZzdhBfsK6t154Z2CR-RpBNEKvyPB6").createFile(imageBlob);
  file.setName("menu.png");
}
```

Comment: That was it indeed.  I failed to see the difference between a content and a blob. Thanks a lot.